# gdal2tiles_parallel only creating one file per zoom level

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles, tile-map-service

I'm trying to create a TMS layer from a gdal VRT dataset. To speed thing up, I'm trying to use gdal2tiles_parallel (https://github.com/GitHubRGI/geopackage-python/wiki/Usage-Instructions-for-gdal2tiles_parallel.py). The command I'm using is:

```
gdal2tiles_parallel -e -z '5-15' --format=PNG sp2014_b321.vrt sp2014_b321_tms/
```

The program starts fine, the directory is created and the *Z* (zoom) folders are also created. However, only one *X* folder is created inside each *Z* folder and only one png is created for each zoom level. The program ends without error but the TMS is incomplete. Has anyone seen this? Any idea how to fix is?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that if I set the output profile to raster -p raster, things work. It looks as thou it does not like the mercator projection. Just not sure how this tile will play with other tiles created with the plain gdal2tiles.py, without using the raster profile option.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at this repository. This works well and also use multiple cores of cpu.

[https://github.com/dixitgoyal/gdal2tiles][1]